# How to add a selection option for font awesome icons using advanced custom field

Tags: wordpress, font-awesome

What I am trying to do for my theme is to have a advanced custom field option where the user can choose which font awesome icon to use.

So, what I am expecting here is to have a select field which shows the list of all the font awesome icons from the font awesome library and returns the value  which I can use to display on my front end.

If there is any other way to do the same without using ACF, I would love that too.

I am not willing to use any plugin here.

Comment: For "If there is any other way..." have you tried [options framework](https://github.com/devinsays/options-framework-theme) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this plugin is useful for you.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields-font-awesome/

Please try it and let me know.

Comment: Well I have tried it. I have figured it out to do the same without using plugin by using all font awesome icons as select choices but the problem is I am not able to set a preview.